# Displaying image in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I'm new to Zend Framework, so forgive me if this is a basic question, but I'm having a heck of a time, displaying an image retrieved from the database.

Edit:  I basically can't access any resource from the /public/ folder.  I'm guessing the front controller is redirecting src requests inside `<link>` tags and `<img>` tags.  Everytime I search, I see people having problems accessing images outside the /public/ folder... but they seem to be fine as long as they're stored under the /public folder.  What am I doing wrong?

I've got the following code in a view partial:

```
<?php
$user = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->user;

?>
<section class="one-fifth first sidebar_profile">
  <div class="one-fifth first about_img"><img src="<?php if($user->picture){echo '/public/img/users/small_thumbs/'.$user->picture;}else{echo "#";}  ?>" alt="name"/>
      <p class="name"><?php  if($user) {echo $user->username; } else { echo "Username";} ?></p>
```

Doing a dump of `$user` gives me the following:

```
object(Zend_Db_Table_Row)[70]
protected '_data' => 
array
  'userID' => string '22' (length=2)
  'username' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'firstName' => string '' (length=0)
  'lastName' => string '' (length=0)
  'email' => string 'test@google.com' (length=18)
  'password' => string '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6' (length=32)
  'picture' => string '4fa3072fe09a5.jpg' (length=17)
  'verified' => string '1' (length=1)
  'confirm_key' => null
  'admin' => null
```

It goes on quite a while, but the point is the file is there.  Looking at the source code from the page that's rendered, the line in question is rendered as:

```
<img alt="name" src="/public/img/users/small_thumbs4fa3072fe09a5.jpg">
```

Should I be using some sort of view helper to display this? I've searched and searched, and couldn't find one.

Comment: Are you using a virtual host? Typically, you would not have /`public` in your frontend urls; the `public` would be part of the virtual host definition.

Comment: yes I am.  The /public/ folder is set as the doc root. I've tried it with/without the /public/ and it still won't work.  Even when I give an absolute definition, I can't access images anywhere across the site. (Or css, unless I use `@import`

Comment: The standard `.htaccess` at the web root will bypass the framework for any files/directories that _actually exist_. If you enter `http://yourhostname/img/users/small_thumbs4fa3072fe09a5.jpg` into the browser, you don't get the image? Another thought: Is `small_thumbs` a folder? If so, you're missing a slash; the correct url would be `/img/users/small_thumbs/4fa3072fe09a5.jpg`

Comment: the missing slash was just a typo, I fixed that but had similar results.  I spent a few hours looking into documentation, and wound up changing my .htaccess file, will post the final as an answer when I'm back on the work machine.  The documentation says that the .htaccess file shouldn't redirect files in the same folder as the doc_root to the front controller, but despite that assurance, for some reason, my app was doing that anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically if you're using frameworks, you shouldn't be doing Logic in your View. You should do the if/else statement in your Controller and in your View simply do:

```
<div class="one-fifth first about_img"><img src="$img"/></div>
```

But as for your question goes, if you copy paste the src attribute in your browser, does it show the picture?

This is my .htaccess. It serves directly any file that extensions match this regular expression, and redirects everything else to my index.php which is my bootstrap file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.(shtml|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|flv|swf|swz)$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

Comment: There is no public controller, and ZF auto redirects any request to that directory. So no way to plug that in as you usually would.  That's why I asked if there was a helper to handle images.  For the record, I Can physically check the image exists.  And yes, it does.

Comment: So the source renders properly and the image shows up separately, but it doesn't show up in your rendered page?

Comment: Also, the if/else logic applies to hundreds of pages across about 50 controllers. And this logic is in a partial, not the view itself.

Comment: What I'm saying is, you can't type the static url into the browser, because Zend tries to route to a `public` controller that doesn't exist. But the file IS there, I just can't get it to render on any page.  I just want to know if there is some sort of helper, used to display url's for resources outside of the application directory.

Comment: oooh. i get it, you need a .htaccess file so that files that end with .jpg or .gif or such sort not to be routed to the controller. That's how Zend does it. Look at the .htaccess file of a sample application

Comment: now ya got it, because I can't display any img tag anywhere. Whether or not it's programmatically generated, or used in a view/layout etc...

Comment: I just can't find any examples of this.  I have a few sample applications that have working `<img>` tags, and my .htaccess file is identical.

Comment: I just pasted my .htaccess file in the answer

Comment: Yep, that's what wound up fixing it for me.  ZF documentation says that the other .htaccess configuration should allow the server to serve up anything in the doc_root, but it just wasn't happening.  Switching my RewriteRule to the above works.