# Unable to access images from public folder to module in zend framework 2

Tags: php, image, zend-framework2

Scenario:

I'm developing a application based on zend framework. I have used skeleton application for my own requirement.

Problem Statement:

I have to use the images for my module which is below.

```
module/Application/view/application/index/index.phtml
```

From this path:

```
public/images/imagename.jpg
```

I am use like the following

```
background-image: url('./images/imagename.jpg');
```

I can see the image in the chrom dev tools 
[image: image on dev tools]

I cant see the image in the browser where i need

Things approached:

- [Displaying image in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441516/displaying-image-in-zend-framework)
- [How to merge Zend Framework 2 module public directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296920/how-to-merge-zend-framework-2-module-public-directories)

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a CSS problem?

Comment: im using the same without zend framework ,it worked and im migrating it

Comment: @Blaatpraat i agree that is a css problem ,i have used inline css way is that a write approach ,it shown after using external css

Comment: The problem is solved ,thanks @Rizier123